# how to find the months between two dates in python? Not based on 30 days based on month value only?

Tags: python, date, datetime, diff

**For example:**

Input:
Start Date: **31-07-2022**
End Date: **01-08-2022**

Output: **2 Months**

Start Date: **01-01-2022**
End Date: **01-01-2023**

Output: **13 Months**

Comment: Your output should be respectively 1 month and 12 months, so July +1 = August. You can check `dateutil` and its class [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/relativedelta.html)

Answer (score 0):

you also needed to mention that the month of starting date is also counted as 1.

```
def month_counter(start_date, end_date):
    start_date = list(map(int, start_date.split("-")))
    end_date = list(map(int, end_date.split("-")))
    
    year_counter =  (end_date[2] - start_date[2]) * 12
    month_counter = end_date[1] - start_date[1] + 1
    return f"{year_counter + month_counter} Months"
print(month_counter("31-07-2022", "01-08-2022"))
```